# Do I lose the subject of the sentence by adding a preposition?

Tags: prepositions, conjunctions, subjects

The following second sentence, continues the first, but I wonder whether using the word `in` causes the second sentence to no longer have a subject, or does it remain from the prior sentence by way of the conjunction `And`?

> The mat is an effective fall break.  And, where linked together, **in** a series of adjacent linked mats provide an effective fall break.

Should I just drop the bolded word **`in`**?

Comment: Yes. That's the easiest way to make it grammatical.

Comment: @JohnLawler But whilst it makes the second sentence grammatical, it changes the meaning. If you simply eliminate the *in* it then says that it is the linked mats (and only the linked mats) which 'provide an effective fall break'. The whole thing is slightly confusing because apart from the second sentence not being grammatical, the two sentences taken together appear to be contradictory. In the first we learn that 'the mat' is 'an effective fall break', but then it seems that 'a series of adjacent linked mats' are required to make it 'an effective fall break'.

Comment: If you retain 'in' then the subject appears to be 'mat' from the first sentence. However, in that case the verb should be 'provides' and the final sentence is ungrammatical in not having an explicit subject.  I think a re-write is in order. It can be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drop the 'in'.  It looks like you were editing and 'in a series' got moved out of the prepositional phrase.  But keep editing:  'Linked' appears twice and is redundant.  'Series' only applies if there is a large horizontal velocity.
"The mat is an effective fall break. Adjacent linked mats can extend the safe landing zone."

Answer (score 2):

The presence of the word "And" as the commencement of your second sentence is a clue that far more brutal editing is warranted to regain a leash-hold on the meaning you intend to convey.

A *single* mat *provides* an effective fall break. Adjacent mats can be linked together to provide an effective fall break over a larger contiguous area.